# get model.predict values in python

Tags: python, output, prediction

I am running a random forest model. I am predicting values using below code

prediction = model.predict(test_x)

I want the predicted values in a list or dataframe from below output.

array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64)

How to do it in Python

Comment: What module are you using? `model` doesn't tell us much.

Comment: from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as rf

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)? What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predict function returns an array object so you can covert it into dataframe as follows.

```
import pandas as pd 
prediction = model.predict(test_x)

cols = prediction[0].keys()
df = pd.DataFrame([[getattr(i,j) for j in cols] for i in prediction], columns = cols)
```

**For your particular case :**

```
import pandas as pd 
prediction = model.predict(test_x)
df = pd.DataFrame(prediction, columns = ['ouput'])
```

Comment: it is giving error - 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: happy to help :)